# Custom ORDER BY in SQLite for string date

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a column "date_time" and many other.
date_time is a string date (because in SQLite there is no date format), e.g. "2020.2.1" means 1st of February of 2020th.

I want to sort by this date 2020.1.1-2020.1.2-...-2020.12.31
I am using:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
ORDER BY date_time
```

And I am getting sorted as a string:

[image]

here is an example:

1. 2020.1.10
   ...

15. 2020.1.29
16. 2020.1.3
    ...

How I can sort it as a date if I am using SQLite and my date is string?

Comment: Use two digits for the month and day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * 
from Table
order by cast(date_time as datetime)
```

Comment: I am getting a not sorted table.
1) 2020.3.15
2) 2020.3.18
3) 2020.1.9

Comment: Everything is good now, I've modified my date from 2020.1.1 to 2020.01.01 by IIF() function. Thank you very much.